# Velocity of a body in free fall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, free-fall

Is it true that the velocity of a body in free fall keep increasing for some time and then becomes constant?
If yes,then can we say that the net acceleration, $a=0$ as the velocity is constant?
Also mention what happened to $g$?

Comment: If there's air resistance, yes.

Comment: Neglect air resistance

Comment: What is your reference frame for expressing the motion quantities?

Comment: @BillN from the level of question, it is inarguably an inertial frame.

Comment: Have you looked at [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) at all?

Comment: Note that _free fall_ and _terminal velocity_ are here mutual exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

From an inertial frame of reference, (if air resistance is factored in) the body's velocity will keep on increasing until it reaches terminal velocity when the downward force g matches the upward force drag (drag depends on the shape of the body). At this point, you can say that a=0 since the velocity is constant. However, if the air resistance is neglected, then the body will have a constant acceleration of 9.8 m/$s^2$ until it hits the surface.

Also, by the way, if there is air resistance the body is not technically in free fall because free fall is only valid in a vacuum.

Comment: If air resistance in included the object is not in free fall.

Comment: True. I will add it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Air resistance will involve the consideration of terminal  velocity which will indeed cause constant velocity when g is qual to upward air drag but neglecting air drag will lead to ever increasing velocity of the object.